# Dynamic and custom div positionning

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this div structure

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="north"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

The outer div is [jQuery resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)
I tried to position the divs with percentage,

```
.north{height:30%}
.center{height:70%}
```

Works perfect, I got this
[image]

Now I am stuck on how to get this:
[image]
Any help?
Don't forget that the outer div is resizable please..

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PnnMa/) is my starting point.

**Edit**
I tried also

```
.panel{display:table;}
.north,.center{display:table-row;}
```

But this doesn't work on IE<8

Comment: your question isn't clear, did you get the top or bottom result? You say 'I got this, then I got this'..?

Comment: If @RenePot's solution does not works then please post HTML or send jsfiddle link

Comment: I said: I got this, then how to get this?

Comment: you tried with display:table and display:table-rown?

Comment: Oh ok, a bit fuzzy formulation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with floats: http://jsfiddle.net/KMWw4/2/

```
.panel {
    width:  300px;
    height: 500px; /* explicit height */
    float: left;
}
.north {
    float: left; display: inline; /*iefix*/
    width:  100%;
}
.center {
    height: 100%;
}

.panel-percent .north {
    height: 30%; /* you can use percentages */
}
.panel-fixed .north {
    height: 100px; /* ... or pixel height */
}

​
```

Comment: awesome! great cross browser solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
.panel {
    position: relative
} 

.center { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

By setting to parent/outer div to position relative, and the inner ones to absolute, you can do a trick like this.

The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PnnMa/1/

Comment: it have the same problem than setting display:table to panel and display:table-row to north and center, doesn't work for IE<7..

Comment: so IE 6? Or also IE 7? Because if it doesn't work for IE6, that's too bad, but those users can probably be ignored by now. Not worth investing in them

Comment: I am developping a Lan web application for a company, most of computers have IE6 (some have IE5), tried to convince them to install FF or at least new IE, they don't want...

Comment: If it is not possible to change browser, then I'd recommend you to tell them these kinds of things are not possible. Perhaps FrameSet?

Comment: doesn't work on the latest Safari (mac) either... but i think you're very close to a more compatible solution

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. ;)

1. Position the 150px object with position:absolute and top:0. (you may need to set left and right to zero too)
2. set the top-margin of the area with a dynamic height to 150px.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KSY6T/3/

```
.panel{
    min-height:150px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;
    /* height:300px; is optional, i just used it for demonstrational purposes */
}

.north{
    position:absolute;top:0px;width:100%;height:150px;
}

.center{
    margin-top:150px;height:100%;
}
```

just resize the parent container see what happens...

you'd have to check for full cross-browser compatibility yourself, 
i've checked it with my browsers and it works just fine on all of them:

- safari 5
- opera 11
- firefox 3.5
- firefox 4